# How to link javascript file to angular app html template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am new to Angular and I have been having a problem trying to use Bootstrap or jQuery JavaScript includes. Below is a snippet of my code. Chrome developer tools tells me:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4200/js/jquery.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyTestApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!--Load JQuery-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/metismenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/blockui-master/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/blockui-master/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/11/18/3821/jquery-angular2-angularcli-how-to

Comment: Your error says it can't find the file (`404 Not Found`). You have relative URLs, meaning the files should be on your server. We can't help you find files on your server.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had the js folder there in the main src folder but it couldnt be referenced directly from that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<base href="/">
```

refers to the root path, therefore, if you don't have those files in your root path they won't load.
You can put them in assets folder (for example) and change the src to assets/....
If you are using angular cli, the 'proper' way would be referencing them in app.scripts in .angular-cli.json

Another option would be installing the jquery library (`npm install --save jquery`) and declaring "$" as jquery variable.

Comment: Thanks so much. I moved my from the main src folder into the assets folder and it worked.